# Why does calling a member member function in a separate thread result in non-deterministic behaviour?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, lambda, member-functions

I broke down my problem to something that is reproducible. In the following code we have a class `printer`. `printer::run` will print a the `id_` of that `printer`. `printer::spawn` will get you a thread with a new printer.

In `main` I am spawning 10 printers. The created threads will be joined at the end of `main`. My expectation would have been that we get the numbers from 0 to 9 in some order every time we run this (this is the "deterministic behavior" from the title). This is not the case. We get other numbers sometimes. Why is that?

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class printer
{
public:
    printer(int i) : i_(i){};
    void run()
    {
        std::cout << i_ << '\n';
    }
    std::shared_ptr<std::thread> spawn()
    {
        return std::make_shared<std::thread>([=]() { run(); });
    }

private:
    int i_;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::thread>> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printer p{i};
        vec.push_back(p.spawn());
    }
    for (auto a : vec)
    {
        a->join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Some thoughts about my expectation:

I would have guessed that we copy the state of the current `printer` when calling spawn, because we capture the state by value (lambda), not by reference.

Even if we would capture by reference, we still copy the state to the new thread.

And even if that is not happening, each thread has its own `printer`. What am I missing?

**Some example outputs:**

(I put all the numbers in one line for brevity)

```
1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -116618192
1513168144, 1513168144, 1513168144, 1513168144, 1513168144, 1513168144, 1513168144, 1513168144, 1513168144, 1513168144
1, 2, 33, , 6, 6, 7, 9, 9, 1344437296
1, 43, 2, 6, , 6, 7, 8, 9, -1194894256
```

Some outputs do not have all 10 numbers...

Comment: please include the actual output in the question. "other numbers" means different order or really different numbers, like eg 42, 314?

Comment: Alright. I will do that.

Comment: If you give me a -1, you will have to point out to me what the issue is. Please explain where I am being stupid

Comment: "you will have to point out to me what the issue is" nope, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325417/358287

Comment: Yes, I know that it is not required. An answer would still help, though

Comment: tbh I dont understand your complaint, I made a suggestion for improvement and while I wasnt the downvoter it is something I would consider worth a downvote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you create and destroy a printer object within the loop that creates your threads. When the loop enters the next iteration, the printer created in the previous iteration has been destroyed, and the thread that you created to reference it will reference this destroyed object.  This is Undefined Behavior.

Essentially all your thread will be using the same `printer` object.  At some point the memory it occupies gets overwritten when it is used to hold other data.

You'll probably want to create an array of printers, so that you can pass a different printer to each thread.

Comment: Okay. But why does this matter? Don`t we copy the state to the new thread?

Comment: @User12547645 No. A _pointer_ to the state is passed to the thread.

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
{
    printer p{i};
    vec.push_back(p.spawn());
}
```

The object `p` has a lifetime that ends at the `}`. Hence the lambda you push in the vector will attempt to call a member function of an object that is no longer alive. Your code has undefined behvior and seeing correct output is only coincidence.